# Literature on many-vs-many classifier

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, evolutionary-algorithm

In the context of [Multi-Class Classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) (MCC) problem,
a common approach is to build final solution from multiple binary classifiers.
Two composition strategy typically mentioned are one-vs-all and one-vs-one.

In order to distinguish the approach,
it is clearer to look at what each binary classifier attempt to do.
One-vs-all's primitive classifier attempt to separate just one class from the rest.
Whereas one-vs-one's primitive attempts to separate one against 
[One-vs-one is also, quite confusingly, called all-vs-all and all-pairs.](http://www.mit.edu/~9.520/spring09/Classes/multiclass.pdf)

I want to investigate this rather simple idea of building
MCC classifier by composing binary classifier in
binary-decision-tree-like manner.
For an illustrative example:

```
       has wings?
     /           \
  quack?         nyan?
  /   \         /     \
duck  bird    cat     dog
```

As you can see the `has wings?` does a 2-vs-2 classification,
so I am calling the approach many-vs-many.
**The problem is**, I don't know where to start reading.
Is there a good paper you would recommend?

To give a bit more context,
I'm considering using a multilevel evolutionary algorithm (MLEA) to build the tree.
So if there is an even more direct answer, it would be most welcomed.

**Edit**: For more context (and perhaps you might find it useful),
I read [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2001576.2001765) which is one of the [GECCO 2011 best paper](http://www.sigevo.org/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=GECCO%20Best%20Paper%20Awards) winners;
It uses MLEA to compose MCC in one-vs-all manner.
This is what inspired me to look for a way to modify it as decision tree builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sailesh's answer is correct in that what you intend to build is a decision tree. There are many algorithms already for learning such trees such as e.g. Random Forests. You could e.g. try [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) and see what is available there.

If you're more interested in evolutionary algorithms, I want to mention [Genetic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming). You can try for example our implementation in [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com). It can deal with numeric classes and attempts to find a formula (tree) that maps each row to its respective class using e.g. mean squared error (MSE) as fitness function.

There are also instance-based classification methods like nearest neighbor or kernel-based methods like support vector machines. Instance-based method also support multiple classes, but with kernel-methods you have to use one of the approaches you mentioned.

Comment: Both looks like really great tools. Thanks a lot. For your HeuristicLab, its GUI-based approach is nice as a learning tool.
But I have a feeling

Comment: But I'm concerned with customization. I saw there the video showing how to edit the flow chart of GA. But will that be enough customization? Or does it allow in some way to integrate traditional coding?

Comment: You can use programmable operators in the operator graph to add some custom code or you can also use visual studio and code your own algorithm as a plugin. There exist some tutorials on the website as well.

Answer (score 3):

What you want looks very much like [Decision Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning).

From wiki:

> Decision tree learning, used in statistics, data mining and machine learning, uses a decision tree as a predictive model which maps observations about an item to conclusions about the item's target value. More descriptive names for such tree models are classification trees or regression trees. In these tree structures, leaves represent class labels and branches represent conjunctions of features that lead to those class labels.

Comment: That wiki page is nice. thanks. Meanwhile, I feel a bit silly not having seen that page before.

Comment: Its not silly, since its not so obvious what to look for unless you know it. Btw, you may also be interested in the related topics (in `See also` section), like `Decision Stump` and `Pruning`.